# Team foundation server doesn't connect

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect to tfs in visual studio 2015 and it gives this error message when i click ok,it gives me this exception

Image :

[image]

Which means in english: The parameter is not in the expected range.

Orignal Stack Track:

> System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie
>   à une instance d'un objet.    à
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid&
>   packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)    à
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
>   à
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

Translated Stack Track:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid&
>   packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

Comment: Could you translate the error info in the picture and exception message to English?

Comment: If you can't connect to TFS through VS2015, could you open the web portal of TFS such as     https://my-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection successful through IE?     Did this phenomenon only occurs with your dev machine ? Try to use your account on another computer.

Comment: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
English: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Le paramètre n’est pas dans la plage attendue
English: The parameter is not in the expected range.

Comment: @patrick-MSFT: Microsoft Translations reverser: https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Emt.aspx

Comment: Whats written in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml ?